# I need to know how to set a maximum buy limit per wallet

Tags: tokens, erc-20

Yeah so I'm creating a eth token and I need to find a way that buyer have a purchasable maximum limit. Can anybody help me with that ? Can't find answer thanks a lot.

Comment: You can store how much each account has bought in a mapping, and revert any purchase above the limit. But having limits doesn't work very well, anyone can have as many accounts as they want a buy with each some more. For that to work you have to implement a whitelist or KYC policy.

Answer (score 0):

In the function that allows purchasing tokens (probably `mint()`), simply include a require check along those lines:

```
require((balanceOf(msg.sender) + _mintAmount) <= maximumLimit, "Cannot exceed limit");
```